# Linear Transformation Geometrically interpretation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Describe the following linear transformations geometrically: $L( u_1, u_2)=(-u_1 ,u_2)$

I don't know how to represent Mathematically. I just know how to prove it a linear transformation and have no idea about geometrically representation.

Comment: Have you tried drawing the vector in a plane and drawing its image?

Comment: Format your equation.

Comment: @Razieh Noori In your edit you missed a comma between $u_1$ and $u_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, I find needless subscripts a little ugly! Consider $L(x,y)=(-x,y)$. This reflects the point $(x,y)$ in the $y$-axis, so that its image is the point $(-x,y)$.

Comment: got it. But if L(x,y)=(-y,x) what would be the answer?

Comment: It's very important that you draw a picture for something like this. Pick a point $A(x,y)$, say in the first quadrant. Make $x$ a little bigger than $y$ so that you can get a better feel for the effect of the transformation. Now compare this to the point $A'(-y,x)$. Now what can you say about angle $AOA'$?